# replace keys in array from other array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays and want to copy keys from first array to second array and keep values on second array:

Arrays:

```
Array ( [8] => yellow [9] => violet ) 
Array ( [0] => blue [1] => orange )
```

Desired output:

```
Array ( [8] => yellow [9] => violet ) 
Array ( [8] => blue [9] => orange )
```

Comment: If you want to change keys of an array, probably you want to look for a more clean and concrete way to store your data?

Comment: I answered, but as @NicoHaase states, it is rarely needed to have the same indexes and it may be how you created or extracted the array data.

Comment: thanks, your answer work perfect to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the keys and combine:

```
$array2 = array_combine(array_keys($array1), $array2);
```